# Comparing unordered_map vs unordered_set

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures, time-complexity

First of all, what is the main difference between them?

The only thing i've found is that `unordered_set` has no operator `[]`.
How should i access an element in `unordered_set`, since there is no `[]`?

Which container is using random access to memory(or both)?

And which one of them faster in any sense or using less memory?

Comment: The're fullfilling different purposes, one is a map, one is a set. If you need a map, use the map. If you need a set, use the set.  performance and memory are _not_ the relevant differences.

Comment: Just to add up what 1201ProgramAlarm said, elements in unordered_set are also keys. So the values that user provides are elements and keys at the same time.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

They are nearly identical.  `unordered_set` only contains keys, and no values.  There is no mapping from a key to a value, so no need for an `operator[]`.  `unordered_map` maps a key to a value.

You can use the various `find` methods within `unordered_set` to locate things.

Comment: Why they are not created like std::queue and std::deque. I mean that queue is adapter for deque. Why unordered_set is not adapter of std::unordered map?

Comment: @GusevSlava: sets require the items to be immutable, and maps have mutable keys. Due to that, neither can be implemented by the other without wasting memory.

Answer (score 2):

you can use iterators to access elements.

```
unordered_set <string> u{
            "Dog",
            "Cat",
            "Rat",
            "Parrot",
            "bee"
};

for(auto& s:u){
     cout << s << ' ';    
} 

unordered_set<string>::const_iterator point = u.find("bee");
```

Answer (score 1):

*How should I access an element in unordered_set (C++17)?*

In C++ 17 a new function `extract` is added to `unordered_set`.
Specially, this is the only way to take move only object out of the set.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/extract

For example if you want third element of your unordered set.
Advance the iterator

```
std::advance(it,2);
```

Then extarct the value

```
s.extract(it).value();
```

Here is the complete code. try on any C++17 compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    //CREATE AN OBJECT
    std::unordered_set<std::string> s;

    //INSERT DATA
    s.insert("aee");
    s.insert("bee");
    s.insert("cee");
    s.insert("dee");

    //NEED TO INCLUDE "iterator" HEADER TO USE "std::advance"
    auto it = s.begin();
    std::advance(it,2);

    //USING EXTRACT
    std::string sval = s.extract(it).value();
    std::cout<<sval;
}
```

Note: if queried for out of bound index, nothing happens. No result.
Try changing your code

```
 //ONLY FOUR ELEMENTS 
 std::advance(it,8);    
 //USING EXTRACT
 std::string sval = s.extract(it).value();
```

Comment: The insert data part can be done more concisely by using an initializer list (`std::unordered_set<std::string> s{"aee", "bee", "cee", "dee"};`). Also `std::next(it, 2)`.